# JWNL (Java WordNet Library) and WordNet

Tags: java, eclipse, wordnet

I'm getting this error when i'm using JWNL:

```
net.didion.jwnl.JWNLException: Unable to install net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary
    at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:34)
    at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:169)
    at wordnet.WordNetHelper.initialize(WordNetHelper.java:25)
    at wordnet.SynReplace.main(SynReplace.java:17)
```

I tried to rename the files in dict index.noun, index.verb to noun.idx, verb.idx and i got the same error, i also tried wordnet 2.1 version for windows and 3.0 for linux 
please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

you have also to rename data.noun, data.verb ..files to noun.dat, verb.dat ...